# Do lawn mowers still cut the grasses if they aren't attached to the ground?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, inertia

A rotary lawn mower cuts the grasses by rotating it's sharp blade on it but if the grasses aren't attached to the ground will they still cut them?
What forces act on this system? I know the answer is yes but I can't imagine how it works.

Comment: This is a commercial product, a "bagless mulching mower."

Answer (score 1):

The force of the blade edge must be greater than that of the interia of the grass. If the blade of grass is freely floating, its inertia is the sole product of its mass. But when rooted, the force of the attachment is factored and a blade of less sharpness/rotational velocity is needed.

I'd be happy to report back on this.

Comment: Force and inertia are different quantities, you can't compare them unless you describe their relationship.

Comment: I'm comparing the grass' resistance to movement to the pressure of the blade edge. If the pressure of the blade edge exceeds the force required to move the leaf, it will cut. Of course this is dependent on the 'sharpness' of the blade, strength of cellulose involved and water content amidst 20 other constituents.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the mass distribution, size and composition of the leaves, especially of their surface, the cross-section and the speed of the blade, air resistance,  etc. A comprehensive answer may require a lot of research.

The fact is that equipment with rotating nylon strings does exactly what you describe without the blades.

Comment: Asked my teacher about this, he said without thinking: yes, because of inertia, but I don't know how does it work.

Comment: The idea is easy to understand by studying the problem of hitting some object on a plane without friction, but  cutting it is more complicated.

Comment: Actually if the blade is sharp, I think we should consider any hit as a cut.

Comment: If by sharp you mean infinitesimal cross-section, then you're right, otherwise the problem becomes complicated.